# Second conditional without "if"

Tags: conditional-constructions

The Second Conditional is used to express something that is unlikely to happen and it can only refer to future events.
According to this explanation I don’t really get these two sentences below, even though they sound fine to me.

An UFC fighter, after defeating his opponent said: “I said I’d punish him”.
I assume the fighter said that because he had a feeling of what  -*would had happened, *right*?*-

> I never thought Trump would win.

Both sentences refer to past events.

Can anyone help me get a **better understanding** (*figure it out/sort it out/clear my head/get my head straight*)?

Comment: It's future in the past, not conditional

Answer (score 1):

These are not conditional.

As well as its use as a modal in its own right, *would* has a second use (its historical origin, in fact), as the past of the modal *will*.

Both of these are reported speech, with backshifting:

> I'll punish him -> I said I'd punish him.

> Trump will win -> I  never thought Trump would win.

Comment: Neither is necessarily reported speech. It is the past of the modal will.